# I have messed up my global directory for installing and running nodes (npm)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, directory, macos-catalina

I am using a mac with catalina

So i wanted to - npm install -g decentraland - but it said access denied or permission denied

so i then blindly followed some instructions that i didn't understand (lesson learn't)

[instructions i followed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDPWe.png)

I did instruction 2 and 3 - i then attempted instruction 4 but it said i don't have permission to edit profile directory

I then skipped to the last instruction which is - Instead of steps 2-4, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don’t want to modify ~/.profile):

Then when i typed - install npm -g decentraland - in the terminal it installed so i thought great i'm a coding genius but when i went to run the npm (dcl start) it couldn't find the npm

I have tried to change the directory back to the original place global nodes/npm should be but i don't know how to do it - this is where i am at the moment [my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgBmk.png)

I would really appreciate some guidance :)
Thanks David

---

**Edit:**

1. This is where my root is, i know it's wrong as i have changed it again but i just thought what is the point in continually changing it if i don't know what it should actually be -

   ```
   David@iMac ~ % npm root -g
   /Users/David/.node_modules/lib/node_modules
   ```

   this is where it was just before i tried guessing where it should be

   `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'` (instructions i followed)
2. This is what my `prefix` is configured as:

   ```
   David@iMac ~ % npm config get prefix
   /Users/David/.node_modules
   David@iMac ~ %
   ```
3. I then ran this -

   ```
   David@iMac ~ % ls/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
   zsh: no such file or directory: ls/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I then ran this:

`npm config set prefix /usr/local`

and i think it has worked as i have the same error message from before

I then ran the install with sudo at the front of it and it worked fine(so 
   happy!) thanks for your help!